# Dark marks on 45-degree oak chamfer: causes and solutions?

Tags: wood, woodworking, routers

I recently put a 45-degree chamfer on an oak parquet piece, but noticed some dark marks on the freshly cut surface. I'm wondering if these could be burn marks? Even though I set the RPM to around 20K for oak, I'm suspecting maybe the speed was too high or I kept the bit in one place for too long. What are your thoughts on what might've caused these marks?

Also, any suggestions on how to remove them? I'm thinking sanding might do the trick, but are there other methods I should consider?

[image]

Comment: It sounds as if you used a variable speed router, and don't appear to understand that the variable speed is set based on the cutter diameter (which you don't even mention, nor exactly what tool you are even using, I had to infer that), more than the species of wood.

Comment: Looks like burn marks to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are burn marks. In your picture the majority of the marks are vertical, across the grain of the wood in a line. This is where the router bit was not going fast enough to maintain proper chip load, and the heat from the cut cooked the wood. The horizontal streaks are possibly where the nature of that grain of wood allowed the heat to cook it faster than the other parts of the wood.

The chips of wood cut off by the bit carry away the heat of the cut. Chip load is how much wood each pass of the cutting edge of the bit takes off. A bit has an optimum chip load, and when that chip load is achieved, the heat of the cut will go away from the bit and the wood into the chips, leaving a mildly warm bit and uncooked wood.

Sanding is one way to remove the burn marks. A reasonable grit, maybe 150, then greater as the project requires. Using a wood block under the sandpaper will help take the burn marks off while avoiding rounding over the sharp edges of the chamfer cut.

Answer (score 3):

Burn marks are a common defect when using routers (and saws) and usually involve dull cutter teeth, failure to keep moving, or both. The bit being loaded with deposits that should be cleaned off is another factor that can come into play.

Sanding or scraping or filing are standard approaches to removing them.